# Embedding an fsolve into an ODE as opposed to using DAE solver in Scilab

Tags: scilab

I am trying to embed a Fsolve to solve this non-linear system in Scilab.

I have solved the problem with the DAE, so I know what to expect, but I am struggling with embedding the Fsolve.

Here is the full copy of the code, DAE included.

I'm not sure where to embed the fsolve function.

```
//dassl approach
//given data
p=[20.086, 8100, 20.086, 20.086, 4050, 1E-17, 1E-11, 1E-17] //mol/kgh
ynames = ['y1' 'y2' 'y3' 'y4' 'y5' 'y6' 'y7' 'y8' 'y9' 'y10']
y0=[1.5776, 0.32, 0, 0, 0, 0.0131, 4.0E-06, 4.0E-06, 0, 0]'//initial conditions 
t0=0
t=linspace(0,1,1000)

dy0 = [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]'
function [f,r]=BatchRXorDassl(t,y,dy)
    f(1)=-p(3)*y(2)*y(8)-dy(1)
    f(2)=-p(1)*y(2)*y(6)+p(2)*y(10)-p(3)*y(2)*y(8)-dy(2)
    f(3)=p(3)*y(2)*y(8)+p(4)*y(4)*y(6)-p(5)*y(9)-dy(3)
    f(4)=-p(4)*y(4)*y(6)+p(5)*y(9)-dy(4)
    f(5)=p(1)*y(2)*y(6)-p(2)*y(10)-dy(5)
    f(6)=-p(1)*y(2)*y(6)-p(4)*y(4)*y(6)+p(2)*y(10)+p(5)*y(9)-dy(6)
    f(7)=-0.0131+y(6)+y(8)+y(9)+y(10)-y(7)
    f(8)=p(7)*y(1)-y(8)*(p(7)+y(7))
    f(9)=p(8)*y(3)-y(9)*(p(8)+y(7))
    f(10)=p(6)*y(5)-y(10)*(p(6)+y(7))
    r=0
endfunction

y=dassl([y0,dy0],t0,t,BatchRXorDassl)
y=y'
tplot = y(:,1)
yplot = y(:,2:11)

clf(11), scf(11)
plot(tplot,yplot)
xlabel('t (s)')
ylabel('C')
legend(ynames,-4)
xtitle('Batch Reactor Concentration Profiles')

////embedded fsolve approach
////given data
//p=[20.086, 8100, 20.086, 20.086, 4050, 1E-17, 1E-11, 1E-17] //mol/kgh
//ynames = ['y1' 'y2' 'y3' 'y4' 'y5' 'y6' 'y7' 'y8' 'y9' 'y10']
//y0=[1.5776, 0.32, 0, 0, 0, 0.0131, 4.0E-06, 4.0E-06, 0, 0]'//initial conditions 
//t0=0
//t=linspace(0,1,1000)
//function ff=fsolvve(y)
//    y1 = y(1)
//    y2 = y(2)
//    y3 = y(3)
//    y4 = y(4)
//    y5 = y(5)
//    y6 = y(6)
//    y7 = y(7)
//    y8 = y(8)
//    y9 = y(9)
//    y10 = y(10)
//    ff(1) = -0.0131+y(6)+y(8)+y(9)+y(10)-y(7)
//    ff(2) = p(7)*y(1)-y(8)*(p(7)+y(7))
//    ff(3) = p(8)*y(3)-y(9)*(p(8)+y(7))
//    ff(4) = p(6)*y(5)-y(10)*(p(6)+y(7))
//    ff(5) = -p(3)*y(2)*y(8)
//    ff(6) = -p(1)*y(2)*y(6)+p(2)*y(10)-p(3)*y(2)*y(8)
//    ff(7) = p(3)*y(2)*y(8)+p(4)*y(4)*y(6)-p(5)*y(9)
//    ff(8) = -p(4)*y(4)*y(6)+p(5)*y(9)
//    ff(9) = p(1)*y(2)*y(6)-p(2)*y(10)
//    ff(10) = -p(1)*y(2)*y(6)-p(4)*y(4)*y(6)+p(2)*y(10)+p(5)*y(9)
//endfunction
//yfsolve0 = [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]'
//yfsolve = fsolve(yfsolve0,fsolvve)
```

Comment: Why do you want to do that ? This is much more efficient to solve it as a DAE. The underlying solver is already implict type, so a few algebraic equations more are not a big deal. But maybe you just want to compute the stationary state ?

Comment: You cannot use fsolve within a right hand side function to convert your DAE in an ODE. However, see the following historical paper on DASSL (https://www.osti.gov/servlets/purl/5882821/) to understand how fsolve could be applied to each step of the underlying scheme.

Comment: I know it is more efficient to solve it as a DAE. The idea here is the solve the algebraic equations inside the ODE equations using fsolve().

Comment: Here is a similar example of what I am trying to achieve

Comment: @StéphaneMottelet

Comment: 'function f=model4a(x,Ca)  //the albebraic equations
    Cb=x(1);Cc=x(2);
    f(1)=Cb*Ke2-Cc  
    f(2)=Ca+Cb+Cc-(Ca0+Cb0+Cc0)
endfunction
function f=model4(t,c)  //the ode's
    Ca=c(1)
    x0=[0.5 0.5]'
    x=fsolve(x0,list(model4a,Ca))  //solve algebraic equa's at each Ca to get Cb,Cc
    Cb=x(1);Cc=x(2)
    r1=k1*Ca-k2*Cb
    f(1)=-r1
endfunction
C0=[Ca0]'
x0=[0.5 0.5]'
x=[]
C3=ode(C0,t(1),t,model4)'  //this gives only Ca
for i=1:length(t)
    x(i,:)=fsolve(x0,list(model4a,C3(i)))'  //Cb,Cc are now calculated from Ca
    x0=x(i,:)'
end
C3=[C3,x]'

Comment: I understand what you want to do, but in your example with 6 ode + 4 algebraic equations, you should first determine by hand which 4 components of y can be obtained by solving the algebraic system. It cannot be done automatically by Scilab.

Comment: In fact you have to solve w.r.t. y(7:10).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code does what you want if you considerably relax the default RTOL and ATOL of ode:

```
p = [20.086, 8100, 20.086, 20.086, 4050, 1E-17, 1E-11, 1E-17] //mol/kgh
ynames = ['y1' 'y2' 'y3' 'y4' 'y5' 'y6' 'y7' 'y8' 'y9' 'y10']
y0 = [1.5776, 0.32, 0, 0, 0, 0.0131, 4.0E-06, 4.0E-06, 0, 0]'//initial condition 
t0 = 0
t = linspace(0,1,1000)

function dy = rhs(t,y1)
    y2 = fsolve([1;1;1;1],list(cstr,y1));
    y = [y1;y2];
    dy = [-p(3)*y(2)*y(8)
           p(1)*y(2)*y(6)+p(2)*y(10)-p(3)*y(2)*y(8)
           p(3)*y(2)*y(8)+p(4)*y(4)*y(6)-p(5)*y(9)
          -p(4)*y(4)*y(6)+p(5)*y(9)
           p(1)*y(2)*y(6)-p(2)*y(10)
          -p(1)*y(2)*y(6)-p(4)*y(4)*y(6)+p(2)*y(10)+p(5)*y(9)];
endfunction

function g = cstr(y2,y1)
    g = [-0.0131+y1(6)+y2(2)+y2(3)+y2(4)-y2(1)
         p(7)*y1(1)-y2(2)*(p(7)+y2(1))
         p(8)*y1(3)-y2(3)*(p(8)+y2(1))
         p(6)*y1(5)-y2(4)*(p(6)+y2(1))];
endfunction

y1 = ode(y0(1:6),t0,t,1e-3,1e-3,rhs)
```

Having to do that show that it is nonsense to proceed that way. Please realize that `fsolve` uses an iterative algorithm and that with this approach you even cannot even take an adequate initial vector for it. If you absolutely want to use ode I can propose a much better approach using implicit differentiation.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I will investigate the error tolerance of the ode.

Comment: Did you run the code ? If so can you validate the result/the answer ?

Comment: The results produced are valid

Comment: OK, can you *validate* the answer please (this is the usage on StackOverflow)